# Deleting all words matching a regex pattern

Tags: java, regex

I would like to remove the character sequences like `"htsap://"` or `"ftsap://"` from a `String`. Is it possible?
Let me illustrate my needs with an example.

**Actual input String:**

```
"Every Web page has a http unique address called a URL (Uniform Resource Locator) which identifies where it is located on the Web. For "ftsap://"example, the URL for CSM Library's home page is: "htsap://"www.smccd.edu/accounts/csmlibrary/index.htm The basic parts of a URL often provide \"clues\" to htsap://where a web page originates and who might be responsible for the information at that page or site."
```

**Expected resulting String:**

```
"Every Web page has a http unique address called a URL (Uniform Resource Locator) which identifies where it is located on the Web. For example, the URL for CSM Library's home page is: www.smccd.edu/accounts/csmlibrary/index.htm The basic parts of a URL often provide \"clues\" to where a web page originates and who might be responsible for the information at that page or site."
```

Patterns I tried: (not very sure it is a right way)

```
((.*?)(?=("htsap://|ftsap://")))
```

and:

```
((.*?)(?=("htsap://|ftsap://")))(.*)
```

Could anyone please suggest here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're escaping your quotes within your sample `String`s, I'll assume you're working in Java.

You should try:

```
final String res = input.replaceAll("\"?\\w+://\"?", "");
```

[Here is a link](http://regex101.com/r/bB5aB2) to a working example of what does this regex match exactly!

---

**How it works:**

It matches and removes any sequence of alphanumeric characters (and underscores), followed by `://` and possibly preceded and/or followed by `"`.

---

EDIT: How to achieve the same result using a `Matcher`?

```
final String input = "Every Web page has a http unique address called a URL (Uniform Resource Locator) which identifies where it is located on the Web. For \"ftsap://\"example, the URL for CSM Library's home page is: \"htsap://\"www.smccd.edu/accounts/csmlibrary/index.htm The basic parts of a URL often provide \"clues\" to htsap://where a web page originates and who might be responsible for the information at that page or site.";
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"?\\w+://\"?");
final StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(input);
Matcher m;
while((m = p.matcher(b.toString())).find()) {
    b.replace(m.start(), m.end(), "");
}

System.out.println(b.toString());
```

Comment: Correct if I wrong, but the `g`lobal flag should be used if `replaceAll` or equivalent method is not being used.

Comment: You're absolutely right! Actually, I used this flag in my example (permalink to **regex101** in my answer).

Comment: why is your regex not just ("(\"?\w+:\/\/"?)") ?

Comment: Thanks ccjmne. The pattern helps!!! instead of using a string replace.. is it possible to use the same pattern under a capturing group or non capturing group? (Matcher class) (To get the Expected resulting string)

Comment: Of course it is! It's just... complicated. I would advise you to use the `String#replaceAll` method in this case, because it really suits your needs! You could still have a look at the edit I made to my answer to show you how to achieve the same result using a `Matcher` :)

Comment: Also, don't forget to accept the answer if your question has been answered ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
"(ftsap|htsap).//"
```

And replace it with `''`

Regex explained:

```
"(ftsap|htsap).//" with flag g
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/JnQ7dY16xaRj0dCs)